# Button not adding to database (eclipse android sqlite)

Tags: sqlite

I am building a simple program that adds,shows,edits and deletes.Here is what happening.If I try to add something with the "add" button,I can only see empty rows.If I edit the empty rows and press the "update" button,everything saves and shos normally? Why is this happening? Here's my code for button:

```
add_save_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ///////// check the value state is null or not
    /////if (valid_earring != null && valid_age != null && valid_weight != null && valid_milkproduction != null && valid_breed != null && valid_dateoffertilization != null && valid_notes != null &&
                //valid_earring.length() != 0 && valid_age.length() != 0 && valid_weight.length() != 0 && valid_milkproduction.length() != 0 && valid_breed.length() != 0 && valid_dateoffertilization.length() != 0 && valid_notes.length() != 0) {

            dbHandler.Add_Contact(new Contact(valid_earring,valid_age, valid_weight,valid_milkproduction,valid_breed, valid_dateoffertilization,valid_notes));
            Show_Toast(Toast_msg);
            Reset_Text();

    //////////}

        }
    });

    update_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        valid_earring = add_earring.getText().toString();
        valid_age = add_age.getText().toString();
        valid_weight = add_weight.getText().toString();
        valid_milkproduction = add_milkproduction.getText().toString();
        valid_breed = add_breed.getText().toString();
        valid_dateoffertilization = add_dateoffertilization.getText().toString();
        valid_notes = add_notes.getText().toString();


        // check the value state is null or not
        //////if (valid_earring != null && valid_age != null && valid_weight != null && valid_milkproduction != null && valid_breed != null && valid_dateoffertilization != null && valid_notes != null &&
        /////       valid_earring.length() != 0 && valid_age.length() != 0 && valid_weight.length() != 0 && valid_milkproduction.length() != 0 && valid_breed.length() != 0 && valid_dateoffertilization.length() != 0 && valid_notes.length() != 0) {

            dbHandler.Update_Contact(new Contact(USER_ID, valid_earring,valid_age, valid_weight,valid_milkproduction,valid_breed, valid_dateoffertilization,valid_notes));
            dbHandler.close();
            Toast_msg = "Data Update successfully";
            Show_Toast(Toast_msg);
            Reset_Text();
        //} else {
        ///    Toast_msg = "Sorry Some Fields are missing.\nPlease Fill up all.";
         ///   Show_Toast(Toast_msg);
        /////////}

        }
    });
```

Comment: Obviously, `Add_Contact` does not work. Thank you very much for keeping that function a secret.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response and the inspiration.I just copied-pasted the "valid" variables from "update" button inside "add_contact" (removed ";" and added "," of course) and everything works fine.